# CSS Media-Query Not Working

Tags: ios, css, media-queries

I'm working on a TAFE assignment to create a full responsive design website but I'm having a problem with the responsive part of it. When it comes to mobile devices (iPad, iPhone, iPod Touch have been tested), the only query they follow it is `screen and (max-width:1000px)` even though my iPad has a screen width of 798px and my iPod Touch a 320px width.

So out of all my media-queries, mobile devices only follow the top two.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1180px) {
    body {
        margin: 0 5%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    body header h1 {
        right: 1%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    body header h1 {
        bottom: 22%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    body #content-wrap #right {
        display: none;
    }

    body #content-wrap #left {
        width: calc(100% - 2.54%);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 690px) {
    body header {
        /* background-position: 40% -100px; */
        background-position: 40% -130px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
    body header h1 {
        font-size: 220%;
    }
}
```

Is there a reason it behaves this way and is there a way to fix it?

EDIT: Desktop browsers follow all these rules when resizing.

Comment: And watch out iWhatever devices, many of them don't change their width with the orientation. They "have" the same width & height portrait and landscape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

➔ [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`